# Scrolling just one flexbox item while another remains fixed using flex-column

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, flexbox, vuetify.js

I have a CodePen demonstrating the issue at https://codepen.io/james-hudson3010/pen/dyMyVMg

I am close to what I want...the top most item with the "Toggle List" button remains fixed while the list scrolls. However, when I get to the bottom of the list, the top most item moves up. The top most item should remain fixed.

Checking the height of the flexbox, it is the expected height. i.e. it is the height of the body - height of header - height of footer

I would have thought the height of the flex items would be determined based on the height of the flexbox, but apparently flex items can grow unconstrained...is this true? why?

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  props: {
    source: String,
  },

  data: () => ({
    showList: true
  }),
  
  computed: {
    filtered() {
      var items = [];
      
      for ( var i = 0; i < 15; i++ ) {     
        let newItem = {
          'name': `Item ${i}`,
          'comment': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut'
        }
        
        items.push( newItem );
      }
      
      console.log( items.length, " ]] ", items );
      
      return items;
    },
    
    children() {
      var children = [];
      
      for ( var x = 0; x < 30; x++ ) {
        let newChild = {
          'name': `Item ${x}`
        }
        
        children.push( newChild );
      }
      
      console.log( children.length, " >> ", children );
      
      return children;
    }

  }
      
      
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app id="inspire" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
      <v-app-bar app color="primary">
        <v-btn text icon>
          <v-icon>mdi-arrow-left</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn text icon>
          <v-icon>mdi-arrow-right</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-app-bar>

      <v-main style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column align-stretch" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">

          <v-card class="pa-3 primary lighten-3" flat>
            <v-btn class="ma-4" @click="showList = !showList">Toggle List</b-btn>
          </v-card>

          <v-card flat color="transparent" height="100%" width="100%" v-if="showList">        
            <v-virtual-scroll :item-height="100" :items="filtered" bench="50">          
              <template v-slot="{ item }">
                <v-list-item>              
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title style="background-color: lightgreen;">{{ item.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                    <v-list-item-subtitle class="text-wrap" style="background-color: lightyellow;">
                      {{ item.comment }}
                    </v-list-item-subtitle>
                  </v-list-item-content>         
                </v-list-item>
              </template>         
            </v-virtual-scroll>        
          </v-card>
          <v-card width="100%" max-width="100%" height="100%" tile style="overflow: scroll;" v-else>                        
            <div v-for="item in 50">Hello {{ item }}<br></div>
          </v-card>
        </div>

      </v-main>

      <v-footer app color="primary">
        <v-img alt="Vue logo" height="40" width="40" max-height = "40" max-width = "40" contain />
      </v-footer>
    </v-app>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: A quick fix would be to add overflow:hidden to #inspire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot's going on in the code. Many conflicts and unnecessary rules. But I get you're using a framework.

Try adding these CSS rules:

```
<v-card flat color="transparent" v-if="showList" style="height: 75%; flex: 1; overflow: scroll;">
```

[revised pen](https://codepen.io/mbnyc/pen/LYNEEQy)

Comment: It appears the only style that is necessary is ```style="overflow: scroll;"``` on <v-card> ... setting the height and flex does not appear to matter. Do they? If so, why?  ( ... now if Chrome would only fix the bug that prevents the scrollbar from showing up ... )

Comment: You may be correct. The lengths may already be covered by the framework styles. I added because `overflow` works hand-in-hand with a defined length. But it looks redundant in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed multiple scrollbar issues (but it did show up in my testing in Chrome).  I'm not sure those issues are browser bugs. Could be something buried in the complexity of the code.

Comment: A scrollbar appears in Chromium, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: In my revised pen, I get a proper scrollbar on `v-card` in Chrome, FF and Edge.

Comment: I do not. May be a OS specific bug at this point...I am using macOS and chrome Version 84.0.4147.105 (

Comment: Could be. I'm on a Windows PC.